# how to access test step from different test case in getXMLHolder

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertions

in the line

```
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("myTestStepName#Response")
```

if I want to refer to a test step belonging to a different test case, how do I do that?

```
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder ("testCaseName#myTestStepName#Response")
```

does not help.

Comment: I am not sure you can access exact step but only test case http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/modularizing-your-tests.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want an object to manipulate XML from another test case, here's an alternative route that gives you an XmlSlurper, assuming you have access to the testRunner:

```
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("testCaseName").getTestStepByName("testStepName")
def responseXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(testStep.properties['response'].value)
```

Source: http://www.robert-nemet.com/2011/11/groovy-xml-parsing-in-soapui.html